# Can I use a single IP with a wildcard SSL?

Tags: iis, ssl

I have two domains on a Windows Server 2012 box with IIS 8:

- domain.com
- dashboard.domain.com

They will both be in the form of:

- https://www.domain.com
- https://dashboard.domain.com

Can I purchase a single wildcard SSL cert as *.domain.com and use it with a single IP address for both domains, or do each domains require their own dedicated IP address?

Thanks.

I apologize if this sounds like it's repeating other posts, but I've read many many posts and the responses really make my eyes glaze over with TLS this, and HTTPSYS that and such.  I was hoping to write this question in such a way that there could be a definitive "single IP" or "two dedicated IP's" answer.  (So my tiny brain can comprehend the response easier.)  No disrespect to those who write these beautiful explanations, I just can't understand them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; that will work fine.

The only reason you need a separate IP address per domain is so that the server knows which certificate to send.
If all of the domains use the same cert (whether because it's a wildcard or through multiple SANs), there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was hoping for.